# Handle csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have an issue when reading csv file
I have csv like

A, B

A1, B1

A1, B2

A2, B4

A2, B5

Can i take a dictionary like {"A": "A1", "B": ["B1", "B2"]}, {"A": "A2", "B": ["B4", "B5"]} ?

Can any one help me on this, please!

Comment: Hi - as StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service, you need to post some code that you have written in an attempt to solve your problem, and explain why it doesn’t work.

Comment: And you need to explain in logical terms how you hope your example of input can be transformed into the output you want.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of out of the box because you have written each line of the CSV with multiple dictionaries, but look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: @jarmod i tried with DictReader, but it's seem like i just can loop all line, can you give me some hint how to get column B to the list where column A have same value

Comment: I'd consider using the original CSV format you've shown, use the standard CSV reader, read one row at a time, search your output dict for the A key, if it's there append the B value to the dict's value associated with the A key, if it's not there add key A with [value B] to the dict. End result would be a dict that looked like: `{"A1": ["B1", "B2"], "A2": ["B4", "B5"]}`. No need to store "A" or "B".

Comment: @jarmod Oh, it's better idea for output format! I will try again with your hint. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the output by columns `A`.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open(path) as csvfile:
    rows = groupby(csv.DictReader(csvfile), key=lambda x: x['A'])
    l = [{'A':key, 'B': [d['B'] for d in v]} for key, v in rows]

print(l)
# [{'A': 'A1', 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}, {'A': 'A2', 'B': ['B4', 'B5']}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` to achieve something similar:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    A   B
0  A1  B1
1  A1  B2
2  A2  B4
3  A2  B5

In [9]: df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[9]: {'A1': ['B1', 'B2'], 'A2': ['B4', 'B5']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!